# Three.js - Issue to render objects using CanvasRenderer

Tags: three.js

I'm facing a issue to render cubes using CanvasRenderer, depends the camera position any cubes lost same parts and show a part of face other cube, as the below images:

In this example, there are two cubes, when the camera in front there aren't problem:

[image]

But, when I change de camera:

[image]

To render I use a array of materials, this is one of:

```
  new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0x006600, ambient: 0xffff00, side: THREE.DoubleSide, overdraw: 0.5 }),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is an artifact of `CanvasRenderer`. The best you can do is tessellate your geometry. For example,

```
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 100, 100, 100, 4, 4, 4 );
```

Or better yet, switch to `WebGLRenderer`.

three.js r.70

Comment: Tessellate is a good way, but dont works in this case, because one of face is transparent. The WebGLRenderer works fine!