# Stop merging of 3D objects when rotated using three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have placed 3d objects with translateZ. They look good when paused and are placed on top/bottom of each other. But when I rotate the scene these objects merger. Can someone tell me how to get rid of this issue ?

[image: Black block is on top of brown, but when I rotate the object, positions got disturb.]

Black block is on top of brown, but when I rotate the object, positions got disturb.

Comment: could you add some images to see what the problem is?

Comment: Are you using `CanvasRenderer`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29020613/three-js-issue-to-render-objects-using-canvasrenderer/29021082#29021082

Comment: @WestLangley Yes I am using `CanvasRenderer`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29020613/three-js-issue-to-render-objects-using-canvasrenderer/29021082#29021082

Comment: @WestLangley Worked perfectly. +1 for that answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I see you have large faces in the models, I think that's a z-buffer problem.
Try logarithmic depth buffer and see whats happens:

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({logarithmicDepthBuffer: true});
```